# Need to append each post element to each ul li of slider

Tags: javascript, foreach, slider, append, blogger

This should be an easy solution.

I have a blog. In each blog post, there is a unique price for every item. On the homepage I have a slider with featured blog posts. I would like to put the price in each li of the slider.

I am not sure the best way to do that.

Price HTML (within every separate post is a different price)

```
<td><span class="item_price">$99.99</span></td>
```

Price CSS:

```
    .item_price{
display: block
width: 100px;   
position: relative;
font: $(description.font);
line-height: 0.84em;
-webkit-text-stroke: 0 none;
 color: $(description.text.color);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #e7d799, -1px -1px 0 #e7d799, 1px -1px 0 #e7d799, -1px 1px 0 #e7d799, 1px 1px 0 #e7d799;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=e7d799,strength=5);
}
```

Slider javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
(function($){$.fn.jCarouselLite=function(o){o=$.extend({btnPrev:null,btnNext:null,btnGo:null,mouseWheel:false,auto:null,speed:200,easing:null,vertical:false,circular:true,visible:3,start:0,scroll:1,beforeStart:null,afterEnd:null},o||{});return this.each(function(){var running=false,animCss=o.vertical?"top":"left",sizeCss=o.vertical?"height":"width";var div=$(this),ul=$("ul:first",div),tLi=$(".car",ul),tl=tLi.size(),v=o.visible;if(o.circular){ul.prepend(tLi.slice(tl-v-1+1).clone()).append(tLi.slice(0,v).clone());o.start+=v}var li=$(".car",ul),itemLength=li.size(),curr=o.start;div.css("visibility","visible");li.css({overflow:"hidden",float:o.vertical?"none":"left"});ul.css({padding:"0",position:"relative","list-style-type":"none","z-index":"1"});div.css({overflow:"hidden","z-index":"2"});var liSize=o.vertical?height(li):width(li);var ulSize=liSize*itemLength;var divSize=liSize*v;li.css({width:li.width()});ul.css(sizeCss,ulSize+"px").css(animCss,-(curr*liSize));div.css(sizeCss,divSize+"px");if(o.btnPrev)$(o.btnPrev).click(function(){return go(curr-o.scroll)});if(o.btnNext)$(o.btnNext).click(function(){return go(curr+o.scroll)});if(o.btnGo)$.each(o.btnGo,function(i,val){$(val).click(function(){return go(o.circular?o.visible+i:i)})});if(o.mouseWheel&&div.mousewheel)div.mousewheel(function(e,d){return d>0?go(curr-o.scroll):go(curr+o.scroll)});if(o.auto)setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll)},o.auto+o.speed);function vis(){return li.slice(curr).slice(0,v)};function go(to){if(!running){if(o.beforeStart)o.beforeStart.call(this,vis());if(o.circular){if(to<=o.start-v-1){ul.css(animCss,-((itemLength-(v*2))*liSize)+"px");curr=to==o.start-v-1?itemLength-(v*2)-1:itemLength-(v*2)-o.scroll}else if(to>=itemLength-v+1){ul.css(animCss,-((v)*liSize)+"px");curr=to==itemLength-v+1?v+1:v+o.scroll}else curr=to}else{if(to<0||to>itemLength-v)return;else curr=to}running=true;ul.animate(animCss=="left"?{left:-(curr*liSize)}:{top:-(curr*liSize)},o.speed,o.easing,function(){if(o.afterEnd)o.afterEnd.call(this,vis());running=false});if(!o.circular){$(o.btnPrev+","+o.btnNext).removeClass("disabled");$((curr-o.scroll<0&&o.btnPrev)||(curr+o.scroll>itemLength-v&&o.btnNext)||[]).addClass("disabled")}}return false}})};function css(el,prop){return parseInt($.css(el[0],prop))||0};function width(el){return el[0].offsetWidth+css(el,'marginLeft')+css(el,'marginRight')};function height(el){return el[0].offsetHeight+css(el,'marginTop')+css(el,'marginBottom')}})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uitX7ROPtTU/Tyv-G4NA_uI/AAAAAAAAFBY/NcWLPVnYEnU/s1600/no+image.jpg";
showRandomImg = false;
aBold = false;
summaryPost = 0;
summaryTitle = 25;
numposts1 = 12;
label1 = "Featured Deals";

function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){
var s = strx.split("<");
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){
s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length);
}
}
s = s.join("");
s = s.substring(0,chop-1);
return s;
}
function showrecentposts(json) {
j = (showRandomImg) ? Math.floor((imgr.length+1)*Math.random()) : 0;
img = new Array();
document.write('<ul>');
for (var i = 0; i < numposts1; i++) {
var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
var pcm;
var posturl;
if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
posturl = entry.link[k].href;
break;
}
}

 for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
 if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
 pcm = entry.link[k].title.split(" ")[0];
 break;
 }
 }

if ("content" in entry) {
var postcontent = entry.content.$t;}
else
if ("summary" in entry) {
var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;}
else va

var textinside = postcontent.substring(postcontent.indexOf("[starttext]")+11,postcontent.indexOf("[endtext]"));
postdate = entry.published.$t;
if(j>imgr.length-1) j=0;
img[i] = imgr[j];
s = postcontent ; a = s.indexOf("<img"); b = s.indexOf("src=\"",a); c = s.indexOf("\"",b+5); d = s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);
if((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!="")) img[i] = d;

//cmtext = (text != 'no') ? '<i><font color="'+acolor+'">('+pcm+' '+text+')</font></i>' : '';
var month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var month2 = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var day = postdate.split("-")[2].substring(0,2);
var m = postdate.split("-")[1];
var y = postdate.split("-")[0];
for(var u2=0;u2<month.length;u2++){
if(parseInt(m)==month[u2]) {
m = month2[u2] ; break;
}
}

var daystr = day+ ' ' + m + ' ' + y;
var trtd = '<li class="car"><div class="thumb"><a href="'+posturl+'"><img width="200" height="170" class="alignnone" src="'+img[i]+'"/></a></div><p><a class="slider_title" href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a></p></li>';

document.write(trtd);
j++;
}
document.write('</ul>');
}
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {     $(document).ready(function(){
$(&quot;#carousel .container&quot;).jCarouselLite({
auto:9999,
scroll: 12,
speed: 50000,    
visible: 4,
start: 0,
circular: true,
btnPrev: &quot;#previous_button&quot;,
btnNext: &quot;#next_button&quot;
});
})})(jQuery)    
</script>
```

Slider HTML:

```
    <div id='carousel'>
<div id='previous_button'/>
<div class='container'>
<script>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot;+label1+&quot;?max-      results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-    script&amp;callback=showrecentposts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>    
<div class='clear'/>
</div>
<div id='next_button'/>
</div>
```

Slider CSS:

```
    #carousel{
width:1000px;
height:253px;
position:relative;
display:block; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}

#carousel .container{
position:absolute;
margin: 0 auto; 
width:900px;
height:253px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel #previous_button{
position:absolute;
left:10px; 
width:24px;
height:253px;
background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--_XlWHrKaTY/UbVUIi1kJII/AAAAAAAAFIQ/Y4Mh8BJ7eqQ/s1600/slide-sides.png) center;
z-index:100;
}

#carousel #next_button{
position:absolute;
right:9px; 
width:24px;
height:253px;
background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--_XlWHrKaTY/UbVUIi1kJII/AAAAAAAAFIQ/Y4Mh8BJ7eqQ/s1600/slide-sides.png) center;
z-index:100;
}  

#carousel ul{
width:100000px;
position:relative;
margin-top:0px; 
left: -35px;
}

#carousel ul li{
background:#fff; 
display:inline;
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:200px;
height:220px;
margin:0 4px 20px 7px;
padding:13px;
}

#carousel ul li a.slider_title{
display:block;
margin-top:-5px; 
color: #395f1e; 
font-size: 13px; 
font-weight: bold; 
line-height: 20px;
}

#carousel a img{
display:block;
background:#fff;
}
```

I hope all the code gives you a better idea of what I am trying to do. I am trying to get every price from each post and append each price to each li of the slider.

I tried:

```
    $(function(){
$(".item_price") .clone() .appendTo("#carousel ul li");
});
```

And it appends all the different prices to the last post in the slider. All stacked on top of each other.

I want the prices to be on top of each image in the slider.

I also tried:

```
    $('.item_price').each(function(index,e){
$('.item_price').eq(index).appendTo($('#carousel ul li').children().eq(index));
});
```

JSON code:

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<center><div id='featured-deals'><a href='http://www.example.com/search/label/Featured%20Deals' title='Show all Featured Deals'><h6>Featured Deals</h6></a></div></center>
<div id='carousel'>
<div id='previous_button'/>
<div class='container'>
<script>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot;+label1+&quot;?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>    
<div class='clear'/>
</div>
<div id='next_button'/>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {     $(document).ready(function(){
$(&quot;#carousel .container&quot;).jCarouselLite({
auto:9999,
scroll: 12,
speed: 50000,    
visible: 4,
start: 0,
circular: true,
btnPrev: &quot;#previous_button&quot;,
btnNext: &quot;#next_button&quot;
});
})})(jQuery)    
</script>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.item_price').each(function(index,e){
    $(e).clone().appendTo($('#carousel ul li').eq(index));
});
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming the blog post always has a single span with class "item_price", this will give you a variable `price`with the contents of the span that you can later use while generating your slider markup.

```
var startIndex = postcontent.indexOf("item_price")+12;
var price = postcontent.substring(startIndex,postcontent.indexOf('<',startIndex));
```

You can add this code before `var textinside=...` is called in your JS function

Comment: Thank you for answering. The code you mentioned and the one similar in my example, both don't work at all. I tried so many different things and the first example I mentioned actually appended so somewhat of a result but not appending to each slider element.

Comment: It doesn't have to append, if there is another solution. Can I just write more code in the slider javascript to call the price class? 

I am not very familiar with var and objects and how to call a class. I did a few hours of research but couldn't find anything similar, so I didn't understand how to write it. 

I was just using append because I am more familiar with jquery.

Comment: Same. If I try it without .clone() the original prices from the main posts disappear and the slider is not breaking, so something is somewhat working but I am just not seeing the prices appear, not even on the last slider image, like my first example attempt.

Comment: I made a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXsge/), as you can see the code works, you may just need to tweak your CSS

Comment: Yeah, the jquery code is correct, which is why it's somewhat working. I am not sure where the problem consists of though, so I am not sure where to begin with tweaking the CSS code. Any suggests?

Comment: Try making a rule for `#carousel .item_price` set position absolute, a high z-index, a large font and a color that contrasts with your images and see if they appear

Comment: Good idea. No such luck. I wish I knew how to call the item_price class in the slider javascript code. Then after it's written, I can just add it to the DIV slider here: var trtd = '<li class="car"><div class="thumb"><a href="'+posturl+'"><img width="200" height="170" class="alignnone" src="'+img[i]+'"/></a></div><p><a class="slider_title" href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a></p></li>';

Comment: Is the price data included in your JSON? Can you post an example of an entry in your JSON feed?

Comment: No the price data is not included in the JSON feed because I am unfamiliar with how to write JSON feed code. I didn't write the slider code. Would it be easy to add it to the JSON feed? That would solve the problem. I tried to do it myself but all I saw was "object (Object)" on every image of the slider (where I wanted the prices to appear). I did it wrong and wasn't sure how to correct it.

Comment: Why don't you post the code that generates the JSON and we'll see if we can make it work

Comment: Okay cool, just added the JSON code. The rest is in the "Slider javascript:" already posted. Thank you!

Comment: okay, but that is the default Blogger.com code. It has nothing to do with the price?

Comment: It links to the page source for that particular label, plus the rest of the whole website code. I was hoping we could just write some code in the json of the slider to call the item_price class. In the same way it calls the images, post titles, and content.

Comment: Oh I see what's happening now... there is no "class" to call, HTML classes are for styling only, what they're doing in the code is parsing the content of each blog post in a very unorthodox manner I must say. I'll update my answer with a similar approach just so you can get this done

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't know the terminally to clearly explain but yes your update is what I was looking for. However, it's still not working. Maybe I did it wrong? I added the 2 codes (the update codes) before the "var textinside=..." in the slider javascript. I also made sure the other code "$('.item_price').each(function(index,e){...." was still in the "/head". Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, every blog post has a span with the same class ".item_price" too.

Comment: OH, I had to put '+price+" in the: var trtd = '<li class="car"><div class="thumb"><a href="'+posturl+'"><img width="200" height="170" class="alignnone" src="'+img[i]+'"/></a></div><p><a class="slider_title" href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a></p></li>'; IT'S WORKING NOW! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR SPENDING SO MUCH TIME ON THIS WITH ME!

Comment: Now, all I need to do is figure out how to style it. lol. As you mentioned, the HTML styling doesn't affect it.